# How to get the value of that input text?

Tags: javascript, php

I have two roles admin and student, if the role is student then I want to hide the admin menu.

Html

```
<input id="role" value='<?php echo $_SESSION[$config["session"]]["role"];?>'>
```

Javascript

```
function loadPage(){
   if($("#role").val() == "student"){
       $("#admin-menu").hide()
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue? You are already getting the value of the input text.

Comment: when I alert it says undifined

Comment: Where did you place your Javascript ? Bottom or top of the page?

Comment: How are you calling loadPage()?

Comment: oh I forgot to mention I'm using external javascript

Comment: You have to make sure the method is being called after the field is being set. Try using $('#role').value

Comment: after the user login

Answer (score 1):

You could add this to your menu container class

`<?= ($_SESSION[$config["session"]]["role"] != admin ? 'hidden' : '') ?>`

It would add class 'hidden' if the user's role is not admin

But the better practice is to use separate views for different user roles or|and do not render admin menu at all

Comment: I HIGHLY DISCOURAGE using this or hiding admin related menus client side with javascript or HTML. A hacker or anyone can easily modify the HTML or Javascript to show the admin menu.  You should PHP echo the entire admin menu if they are admin. PHP happens server side and can not be modified.

Comment: @DSander That depends on what they can do with it.  Presumably, the backend is protecting whatever API calls are being made, etc.  :-)

Comment: @DSander yes, ofc. The best way is to render separate views for any given role, so that there is no any possibility for security issues, but sometimes we need to work with what we have, or "secure admin menu" is just some random container with red background :)

Answer (score 1):

Call your function after document load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
loadPage();
});
```